# Obtaining sigma of a Normal distibution in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the mean and the percentile 60 of a Normal Distribution. I need to obtain a random array of numbers form it with those two values in Matlab.
Is this somehow posible?

Thanks

Comment: `normrnd` if you  have the stats toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of what your looking. I understood that you want to know the standard deviation for a certain value of a quantile at 0.6 (percentile = quantile * 100)?

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Quantile_function). (look at the quantile function for a mean μ and variance σ2).

From this you have all you need:

- p = 0.6
- F^-1(p) is your percentile
- erf^{-1} is erfinv

Get the \sigma it's your standard deviation and then to generate your vector simply use x=randn(nbSamples,1)*sigma + mean

Answer (score 0):

```
m = 2; %// number of rows
n = 5; %// number of columns
mu = 3.2; %// mean
p60 = 0.4; %// 60-percentile

sigma = p60 / norminv(.6); %// compute sigma from p60
result = mu + sigma*randn(m,n); %// random numbers with desired distribution
%// Or: result = normrnd(mu, sigma, m, n);
```